# Originate call on multiple extensions and Hangup if one is answered

Tags: lua, asterisk, ivr, pbx, asteriskami

I am using Asterisk Manager Interface to originate call. I am making Outbound call and then originate calls on multiple extensions. The problem is that the other extensions doesn't get disconnected if call has been answered on one of the extensions. I want to achieve behaviour similar to Dial method.
e.g.

```
Dial(SIP/1000&SIP/1001&SIP/1003)
```

Here if the call is answered by one of them (1001,1002,1003) . Others are automatically disconnected.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

You can do originate to dialplan, in dialplan you can do like you described.

For that you have use channel type Local

```
Dial(Local/800@ringgroups/n)
```

Comment: I tried this, but here also it was just ringing the first extension mentioned in the ring group and then Hangup

Comment: It work like you asked. If it is not like you expect, you have describe more carefully what you need or hire expert.

Comment: I might be doing something wrong in that case, It would be great help if you could share sample config.